# Scala upper type bound

Tags: scala, types, type-bounds

```
class P(name: String)
class E(_name: String, role: String) extends P(_name)

def testF[T <: P](x: List[T]): List[T] = x

val le = List(new E("Henry", "Boss"))
class Test[R <: E](l: List[R]) {
  def r[O <: P] (): List[O] = testF(l)
}
```

I get:

```
Error:(8, 38) type mismatch;
 found   : List[R]
 required: List[O]
  def r[O <: P] (): List[O] = testF(l)
```

My intuition suggests that this should have worked because `T` has a tighter upper type bound than `O`.

**** EDIT ****

```
  def findNN[A, B <: A, C <: A, T] (seq: Seq[B], n: Int, center: C, distance: (A, A) => T)
  (implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Seq[B] = {
    import ord._
    val ds = seq map ( (a: A) => distance(a, center))
    val uds = ds.distinct
    //#TODO: replace quickSelect with median-of algorithm if necessary
    val kel = quickSelect(uds, n)
    val z = seq zip ds
    val (left, _) = z partition Function.tupled((_, d: T) => d <= kel)
    left map {t => t._1}
  }
```

OK, let's have a look at the example above.

The superclass `A` provides the method distance.
I would like to use the function `findNN` on a `seq[B]` having a center in a class `C`. `distance` should work because it works on `A`

Based on feedback provided, there's no way to simplify the type signatures above.

Comment: You have given a strange example. The type parameter `T` is never used in your `testF` function . `def testF[T <: P](list: List[T]): List[T] = list` will work if you do `testF(List(new P("a"))`.

Comment: OK, I cleared up my head and wrote a toy example which I think reflects the current setting.

Comment: The `r` function again has an unused type parameter `O`. You can not limit the type in a function if the type is never used.

Comment: Disregarding upper bounds for a moment, writing something like `def foo[A]: List[A] = List("bar")` also doesn't compile.

Comment: @PeterNeyens: do you think that the function `findNN` could work? I am refactoring my code in the meanwhile..

Comment: It compiles, and it looks like it should do what you want it to do, without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: OK, I have understood how the thing works. Thanks. If you answer, I will accept. "Disregarding upper bounds for a moment, writing something like def foo[A]: List[A] = List("bar") also doesn't compile." should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to limit the type of the result using a type parameter `R` (with an upper bound type `E`), while you are not using the type `R` in your function.

An example of a correct use of a type parameter (with an upper bound):

```
def testF[T <: P](list: List[T]): List[T] = list

testF(List(new P("Tom"))) 
// List[P] = List(P@43bc21f0)
testF(List(new E("Jerry", "Mouse")))
// List[E] = List(E@341c1e65)
```

An incorrect use of a type parameter:

```
// does not compile, what is A ??
def foo[A]: List[A] = List("bar")
```

Answer (score 2):

You made misprinting, you need >: rather then :<

```
class P(name: String)
class E(_name: String, role: String) extends P(_name)
def testF[T >: P](): List[T] = List(new P("Henry"))
```

Comment: Nope. I would like this to fail for a supertype of `P`. Let me think of a better example.

Comment: So you need "P or any class that is not subclass of P"? Can you provide example, where you need this?